# Android Studio Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The version I have is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="google_play_services_version">7327000</integer>
</resources>
```

So when I added it in my dependices

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.27'
```

I kept getting the error

Error:Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.27

```
<a href="openFile">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Open in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

I have the play service installed and the repo. Can someone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to work after I added a +

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.+'
```

Comment: The only ones in the 7.x.y series that I see in the repository are 7.0.0 and 7.3.0. I do not know where you got the 7.3.27 version number from.

Comment: Here http://www.apkmirror.com/uploads/page/4/?app=google-play-services for example.